# What is autoload in php?

Tags: php, autoload

what is autoload in PHP?

Comment: Retagged: removed php5.3 tag as this is a php5-specific question.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This will be of help to you about usage of autoload. http://ditio.net/2008/11/13/php-autoload-best-practices/

It's a magic function that helps you include / require files using class name.

```php
function __autoload($class_name) 
{
    require_once $DOCUMENT_ROOT . “/classes/” . $class_name .“.php”;
}
```

**It's deprecated at PHP 7.2.0 and spl_autoload_register is recommended for that purpose.**

Comment: The [_autoload](http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) function as advised in this article should not be used anymore, the [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) function is preferred.

Comment: This link could break, please place the most vital parts of the link inside the answer.

Answer (score 40):

**What is autoloading?**

Every time you want to use a new class in your PHP project, first you need to include this class (using include or require language construct, that’s right this are not functions). However if you have __autoload function defined, inclusion will handle itself.

```
include "classes/class.Foo.php";
 
$foo = new Foo;
$foo->start();
$foo->stop();
```

Basic Autoloading Example

```
function __autoload($class_name) 
{
    require_once $DOCUMENT_ROOT."classes/class.".$class_name.".php";
}
 
$foo = new Foo;
$foo->start();
$foo->stop();
```

[PHP Official](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)

[Other](http://ditio.net/2008/11/13/php-autoload-best-practices/)

#### Update

PHP 5 introduced the magic function __autoload() which is automatically called when your code references a class or interface that hasn’t been loaded yet.

The major drawback to the `__autoload()` function is that you can only provide one autoloader with it. PHP 5.1.2 introduced `spl_autoload()` which allows you to register multiple autoloader functions, and in the future the `__autoload()` function will be deprecated.

The introduction of `spl_autoload_register()` gave programmers the ability to create an autoload chain, a series of functions that can be called to try and load a class or interface. For example:

```
<?php
function autoloadModel($className) {
    $filename = "models/" . $className . ".php";
    if (is_readable($filename)) {
        require $filename;
    }
}

function autoloadController($className) {
    $filename = "controllers/" . $className . ".php";
    if (is_readable($filename)) {
        require $filename;
    }
}

spl_autoload_register("autoloadModel");
spl_autoload_register("autoloadController");
```

Comment: Please don't use `__autoload()`. It's [better to use spl_autoload_register](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651509/someone-explain-spl-autoload-autoload-and-spl-autoload-register)

Answer (score 30):

Here is the official documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

In short, it just allows you to define search paths for classes so you wouldn't be required to include the files containing them manually.

I suggest you should develop a habit of searching php.net by just appending function names or obvious keywords to the address. That's how I found php.net/autoload. It's quite convenient like that.

Comment: Also see: https://phpbestpractices.org/#auto-loading

Comment: Some php concepts are better explained by other users than php documentation. By providing a link to explanation on SO defeats its purpose.

Comment: @TadasV. Agreed, not just some, but A LOT of them.

Answer (score 1):

```
an __autoload() 

//function which is automatically called in case you are trying to use     
//a class/interface which hasn't been defined yet.

function __autoload($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
}
```