# PHP default spl autoload function do not load parent of class in namespace

Tags: php, class, namespaces, parent, autoload

I cannot autoload parent of class in namespace. Without inheriting child class is loaded; but child is not able to autoload parent class.

File structure:

```
/index.php
/lib/router.php
/lib/ns1/parent1.php
/lib/ns1/child1.php
```

index.php:

```
spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
spl_autoload_register();
require '/lib/router.php';
```

/lib/router.php

```
$child1 = new ns1\child1();
```

/lib/ns1/child1.php

```
namespace ns1;
class child1 extends parent1 {}
```

/lib/ns1/parent1.php

```
namespace ns1;
class parent1 { function __construct() {} }
```

When I remove "extends" part from child1 everything is ok.
With "extends" part I have error:

> Fatal error: spl_autoload(): Class parent1\child1 could not be loaded in /lib/ns1/child1.php

Is there some way how to do that with built in default spl autoload function?
Many thanks for any help.

Comment: `parent` is a [reserved word](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.classes.php#reserved.classes.special), it may only be an example but if it is it's a bad one

Comment: of course it is only example :) names are for better understanding. but i correct it...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution which works for me in this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7987085/5208203

Just add set_include_path() to file index.php:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR."/lib");
spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
spl_autoload_register();
require '/lib/router.php';
```

But I'm not sure about performance, may be it is just workaround for another failure I have in my class definitions...