# how to use $this in function spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, spl

```
 public function run()
{
    spl_autoload_register(array($this, 'loadClass'));
}
```

Why use `$this` here?
How should `spl_autoload_register()` be used?

Comment: `How to use spl_autoload_register() ?`... Did you try google for it, to find description and examples?

Comment: yes, but I still don't understand $this, some examples like this are used to call a static function.for example spl_autoload_register(array('className','functionName')).$this is a object or a string?

Comment: HTH: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523479/what-does-the-variable-this-mean-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [someone explain spl\_autoload, \_\_autoload and spl\_autoload\_register?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651509/someone-explain-spl-autoload-autoload-and-spl-autoload-register)