# PHP: check if 'use' a valid class

Tags: php

If I fail to `include` a file in PHP, it reports.

But how do I know I successfully import `GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar` Class ?

And how do I know it is a valid Class ?

```
namespace GuzzleHttp;

use GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar;
use GuzzleHttp\Promise;
```

Comment: The `use` statement does not load the class file. You have to do this with either `include` or `require`, or by using an autoload function.

Comment: Use composer autoloader, easy

Comment: `class_exists()` will trigger autoload of a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays most application use autoload feature from composer.

You can check if a class exist via code:

```
if (!class_exists(CookieJar::class)) {
    throw new Exception('class not found');
}
```

but `class_exists` probably more useful when you do dynamic stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that the `use` statement will **NOT** include that class, therefore it would be impossible to detect if this (statement) was succesful.

However if you would try to instantiate one of the *imported* classes and the import would have failed, you'd get an error.

You usually use an autoloader for this, such as [composer](https://getcomposer.org), but you can also write one yourself. More information about this at this page: [What is Autoloading; How do you use spl_autoload, __autoload and spl_autoload_register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651509/what-is-autoloading-how-do-you-use-spl-autoload-autoload-and-spl-autoload-re)