# Using spl_autoload_register without using include

Tags: php, autoload

I've seen a lot of threads here and in other forums that asked this a lot of times, but I still see using the `include` function of PHP in the answers?

how can I use this function, not using totally the `include` function?

Thank you

Comment: there are examples on the php.net page which explain just that. http://php.net/spl_autoload_register

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/7987085/2119863

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Autoloading; How do you use spl\_autoload, \_\_autoload and spl\_autoload\_register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651509/what-is-autoloading-how-do-you-use-spl-autoload-autoload-and-spl-autoload-re)

Comment: I'm pretty much sure it's not a duplicate, I have clarifications in using the the spl_autoload function. Other threads does not advise otherwise. This is not duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

> how can I use this function, not using totally the include function

You cannot totally not use `include` and that is not the point of using autoloader as you usually need to at least  include the autoloader ;). That autoloader is the regular PHP code that is being called by PHP  when unknown class use is attempted in the code. It is expected to include right file to make the class known, and the code continues as you'd explicitely `include` right file by hand in your code. So the main benefit shows up when your code uses classed (OOP) - you do not need to care if you included the class you are about to instantiate the object of or not. You just do `new Foo()` or call `Something::methodName()` and if all is set up right it will work.

Comment: Thanks Marcin, I think the key to your answer "explicitly include right file".

Answer (score 0):

The function [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) is used to register a callback into the autoloader queue.

The PHP autoloader is a functionality of the PHP interpreter that, when a class is not defined, calls the functions registered in the queue, one by one, asking them to load the class, until the class becomes available. It the class is still not available after all the functions were invoked, the interpreter triggers a fatal error.

The autoloader doesn't perform any magic. It is the entire responsibility of the registered functions to make the class available. Most of them use the name and namespace of the missing class to figure out the path of the file that contains the declaration of the class and [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) it.

That's how the thing works. There are not many ways to produce a class in PHP and, for a **reusable** autoloader callback, the list starts and ends with [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)<sup>1</sup> ([`include_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php), [`require`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) or [`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) can be used as well but they don't make any difference in this case.)

The autoloader callback itself stays in separate file (for reusability) and usually that file also contains its registration as autoloader callback (the call to [`spl_autoload_register`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php)). All your code have to do is to [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) this file once in every file that is an entry point of your application.

All things being equal, your application needs to use `include` at least once and once is also the maximum required number of usages for it. The autoloader callback also uses `include` (probably also only once) but you don't write autoloader callbacks every day. If you wrote one and you wrote it well you can reuse it. Most people never wrote an autoloader callback and they will never write one.

Using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) is easy and if you follow the [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) rules of naming the files of your project, [Composer](https://getcomposer.org) can generate an autoloader for your project that knows how to load your classes (behind the scene it uses `include`, of course). All you have to do is to run `composer init` in the root directory of your project, run `composer install` and write `include 'vendor/autoload.php';` in the file that represents the entry-point of your application. No other uses of `include` are required.

---

<sup>1</sup> An autoloader callback is not required to `include` another file to make the class available. It can generate the code of the class on the fly and [`eval()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)-uate it, but the use cases of such approach are very limited. It is used by the testing suites f.e., to generate mock classes.