# What does everyone mean by: 'spl:_autoload() is default implementation of __autoload()'

Tags: php, autoloader, spl, spl-autoloader

I got confused with one thing about php autoloading stuff: the `spl_autoload()` function. In every answer I found that this function is default implementation of `__autoload`. Shouldn't PHP define default implementation of `__autoload()` in itself and then if I explicitly create `__autoload()` it will just override it?

If i don't explicitly define `__autoload()` function in my php file, will be there the default implementation? Is `spl_autoload()` some kind of internal function, if yes, why is it in php doc then?

(If it's not an internal function)In every spl_autoload() example there isn't any call to this function, only `spl_autoload_register` with no parameters, `spl_autoload_extensions` and so on. why so? What am I missing?

Quoting from: [What is Autoloading; How do you use spl_autoload, __autoload and spl_autoload_register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651509/what-is-autoloading-how-do-you-use-spl-autoload-autoload-and-spl-autoload-re)

> ```
> set_include_path(get_include_path().PATH_SEPARATOR.'path/to/my/directory/');
> spl_autoload_extensions('.php, .inc');
> spl_autoload_register();
> ```
>
> Since spl_autoload is the default implementation of the __autoload()
>   magic method, PHP will call spl_autoload when you try and instantiate
>   a new class.

So if I won't call `spl_autoload_register()`, it won't register the default implementation? Does the `spl_autoload` look into extensions set by `spl_autoload_extensions();` and then import all files with these extensions from include path? Repeating question mentioned earlier: is `spl_autoload()` internal function?

**I know that `__autoload()` is deprecated and I should use `spl_autoload_register()`. I just want to make sure that I know how it all works.**

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Autoloading; How do you use spl\_autoload, \_\_autoload and spl\_autoload\_register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651509/what-is-autoloading-how-do-you-use-spl-autoload-autoload-and-spl-autoload-re)

Comment: @Dipakchavda I have seen that post

Comment: Don't care about `__autoload` - that function is deprecated. Use `spl_autoload_register` and use your own autoload function

Comment: @Philipp That's the kind of answer that I am not looking for. I know that it is deprecated, I just want to know how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Repeating question mentioned earlier: is `spl_autoload()` internal function?

That's just the "default value" for `spl_autoload_register` if you don't pass an parameter. You could also call this function standalone, if you want to. The behaviour of spl_autoload could be configured with `spl_autoload_extensions` and `set_include_path`.

Internally `spl_autoload` takes the full qualified class name(fqcn) as the path to look for a class implementation. (Maybe with string replacements for directory seperators). Afterwards, it searches in every element of the class_include_path after the given file.

```
spl_autoload_extensions(".php");
spl_autoload_register();
$foo = new \foo\Bar();
// now spl_autoload tries to load the file foo/Bar.php inside your class path.
```

If you need something more complicated, you have to create your own callback for the autoloader. I.e. something like this

```
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    $path = 'classes' . DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR;
    // dont care about case
    $class = strtolower($class);
    // replace _ with DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR
    $name = str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR, $class);
    // don't care about windows/unix
    $name = str_replace('/', DIRECTORY_SEPERATOR, $name);
    $file = $path . $name . '.php';
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        include ($file);
    }
});
```

Note: The example above doesn't care about the value of `spl_autoload_extensions` or `set_include_path`.