# Which is the best way to require file in PHP class

Tags: php, include

I created a class that includes some others files

```
require_once('APIUtils.php');
```

in different functions.

The question is:

Is it better to call require at the top of the class or to choice each one in each function?

Because I've like 20 require in 40 functions.

Comment: if you have that many requires.. I'd wager a bet to say you need some restructuring ...

Comment: Take a look at autoloading classes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651509/what-is-autoloading-how-do-you-use-spl-autoload-autoload-and-spl-autoload-re

Comment: Perfect, thanks, it's exactly what I was looking for @claudio

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is Autoloading; How do you use spl\_autoload, \_\_autoload and spl\_autoload\_register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651509/what-is-autoloading-how-do-you-use-spl-autoload-autoload-and-spl-autoload-re)