# PHP autoload can't find the class

Tags: php

Autoloader code:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoader');

function myAutoLoader($className){
    $path = "/classes/";
    $extension = ".class.php";
    $fullPath = $path . $className . $extension;
    echo $fullPath;
    if(file_exists($fullpath)){
        require $fullPath;
    }
}
?>
```

And it is throwing error, that class is not found for some reason. I even tried to print out the fullpath variable, and it matches the path, in which class is located.
File structure: https://prnt.sc/17v3qsk
Fullpath value: "/classes/DatabaseConnect.class.php"

Sample index.php code that I am trying to use it in:

```
<?php
include 'includes/autoloader.inc.php';
$dbConnect = new DatabaseConnect('127.0.0.1','root','','test');

if($dbConnect->connect_errno){
    die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $dbConnect->connect_error);
}
echo 'connected successfully';
?>
```

EDIT 1:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoader');

function myAutoLoader($className){
    $path = "/classes/"; // <-- Notice the ".."
    $extension = ".class.php";
    $fullPath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . $path . $className . $extension;
    echo $fullPath;
    if(file_exists($fullpath)){
        require $fullPath;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is Autoloading; How do you use spl\_autoload, \_\_autoload and spl\_autoload\_register?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651509/what-is-autoloading-how-do-you-use-spl-autoload-autoload-and-spl-autoload-re)

Comment: That path can't be right. Project root is never in the file system root, not even in Docker setups.

Answer (score 0):

The built `$fullPath` will look like this: `/classes/DatabaseConnect.class.php`. Now the problem is that this is an absolute path, not relative to the project root directory.

In your case, because the `autoloader.inc.php` is in the `includes` folder, which in turn is on the same level with the `classes` folder, the following should work:

```php
<?php
spl_autoload_register('myAutoLoader');

function myAutoLoader($className){
    $path = __DIR__ . "/../classes/"; // <-- Notice the ".."
    $extension = ".class.php";
    $fullPath = $path . $className . $extension;
    echo $fullPath;
    if(file_exists($fullpath)){
        require $fullPath;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it does not solve the issue. It gives the correct path with document root(see the edit 1) and I can even open it up in the windows explorer

Comment: I've updated the code with a newer version of building the path. Please check it out.