# How does Laravel load PHP files

Tags: php, laravel, require

The first three lines of `database\seeds\DatabaseSeeder.php` are:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder { ... }
```

The `Illuminate\Database\Seeder` namespace points to `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Seeder.php`.

How does Laravel require the files from relatively complex directory structures so easily just by using its namespaces?

Where are the files are actually loaded with `require` (like: `require 'path\to\file';`)?

Comment: It uses psr loader check this [link](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is autoload in php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607543/what-is-autoload-in-php)

Answer (score 5):

**Laravel**

Laravel uses [PSR-4 autoloading](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) via [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to load files. Mainly, composer manages how classes and files are loaded.

**Custom Framework**

Most PHP frameworks today, like Laravel, use [spl_autoload_register()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) to handle the dynamic loading of class files when a class has not been loaded. PSR-4 is a community standard from the PHP-FIG used to describe the format of classes and how their files should be written.

The [PHP-FIG has example autoloaders](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md) you can modify for your own projects.

**Relevant links**

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php
- http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/
- https://getcomposer.org/
- https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md

Answer (score 3):

If you open the [`index.php` file](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/index.php) you will see there in line 22:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

This require the `autoload.php` file, which [loads the `composer` autoloader](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/bootstrap/autoload.php):

```
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Which handles all the [automatic loading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) of the different files (classes/libraries).